# Roslyn CTP - Random Code Modification

Tags: c#, genetic-programming, roslyn

I have been experimenting with the Roslyn API in a genetic programming type of scenario.  It appears like a great way to do that type of programming, but the actual implementation of simple scenarios doesn't seem very straightforward, which means I probably don't have a good understanding of how to use this API properly.  Here is a simple program I am trying to modify in my experiments:

```
string treeText = @"using System;
                                using System.Collections.Generic;

                                namespace TestProgram
                                {
                                    class Program
                                    {
                                        static void Main(string[] args)
                                        {
                                            var myVar = 3;
                                            string myString = ""Hello World"";
                                            List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
                                            Console.WriteLine(myString + myVar);
                                            Console.ReadLine();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }";

SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxTree.ParseText(treeText);

var compilation = Compilation.Create("test.exe",
        syntaxTrees: new[] { tree },
        references: new[]
            {
                new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
                new MetadataFileReference(typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.Location),
            });

        SemanticModel model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);
```

Just as a simple example let's say I somehow "randomly" decided I want to insert a new method invocation using the myString instance.  What would be an efficient way to figure out what methods I could invoke off of that instance?  What would then be the best way to create the necessary MethodInvocationSyntax (once I chose a specific method to use) from the symbol information?  I found a method called ResolveOverloads on the SemanticModel class which appears where I need to end up, but I am having some difficulty figuring out an efficient path to the parameters this method requires.  Is that even the right path to go down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get the `VariableDeclaratorSyntax` for your variable, for example:

```
var variable = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes()
                   .OfType<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>()
                   .Single(v => v.Identifier.ValueText == "myString");
```

Next, get the `LocalSymbol` for this variable from the `SemanticModel`:

```
var variableSymbol = (LocalSymbol)model.GetDeclaredSymbol(variable);
```

Then you can get a list of methods you can invoke on this variable based on its type. You can either simply get all members of the type that are instance methods:

```
var methods =
    variableSymbol.Type.GetMembers()
                  .OfType<MethodSymbol>()
                  .Where(m => !m.IsStatic && m.MethodKind == MethodKind.Ordinary);
```

Or, if you wanted to include extension methods, you could use `LookupSymbols()`:

```
var methods = model.LookupSymbols(
    variable.GetLocation().SourceSpan.Start, variableSymbol.Type,
    options: LookupOptions.IncludeExtensionMethods)
                   .Where(m => !m.IsStatic);
```

You can then choose one of the available methods based on your logic and create `InvocationExpressionSyntax` (the following code assumes it's a parameterless method):

```
var invocationExpression =
    Syntax.InvocationExpression(
        Syntax.MemberAccessExpression(
            SyntaxKind.MemberAccessExpression,
            Syntax.IdentifierName(variableSymbol.Name),
            (SimpleNameSyntax)Syntax.ParseName(selectedMethod.Name)));
```

You would then need to figure out where in your method to add the expression and what to do with its result (if anything).

Comment: Thanks again svick!  I'm going to experiment with the code in your answer here and see if I can answer my own question about adding methods that take parameters.  If I am still having difficulties with the ResolveOverloads method, then I will just post a new question.

Comment: One tip: you should always use LookupSymbols for something like this, since you also need to make sure the method is accessible at the call site. LookupSymbols does that, while GetMembers won't.